# SVAR Model with Short run restrictions

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

I am currently working on implementing `SVAR` model in an economic analysis. I have 10 variables in my analysis and currently struggling to incorporate the short run restrictions.

Here is an example with four variables say Y1 (GDP), Y2(Exchange rate), Y3 (interest rate) Y4(Bank risk). I wanted to implement the following short term restrictions.

[image]

I went through the some textbooks and the examples  were starting with short run ordering. Unlike here where I do not have an order and hence making the matrix non triangular.